# In a multitenant application How can I check tenant data where the application is registered in the azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have 2 SharePoint sites from different organizations (tenants):

- Tenant 1: abc.sharepoint.com
- Tenant 2: xyz.sharepoint.com

The necessary permissions for an application have been registered and given on the azure portal for Tenan 1 'abc.sharepoint.com' so that it can be accessed with Tenant 2 users: 'xyz.sharepoint.com'

- Authentication works fine
- The access to the data of the sharepoint lists work correctly when I am authenticated with the users of Tenant 1 'abc.sharepoint.com'

What I would like is that authenticated with a user of Tenant 2 'xyz.sharepoint.com' you can consult the data of sharepoint, Example:

When I make the request:

1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root   or  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xyz.sharepoint.com

   It returns the information satisfactorily, because it consults the site of 'xyz.sharepoint.com' since the users are from that tenant

... but when I consult specifying the tenant 'abc.sharepoint.com'

2. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc.sharepoint.com

   Returns the following error:

   `{
   "error": {
       "code": "invalidRequest",
       "message": "Invalid hostname for this tenancy",
       "innerError": {
           "request-id": "c0a8fa51-245b-4d1e-bf0b-5f32b6c0eb26",
           "date": "2019-08-17T16:27:57"
       }
   }
   }`

One authenticated with the users of another tenant. How can I check the information that the application is registered?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use an access token got from one tenant to access another tenant.

If you want to do so, you need to:

1. Add the user of Tenant 2 'xyz.sharepoint.com' as a guest into Tenant
   1 'abc.sharepoint.com'. See [Quickstart: Add guest users to your directory in the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).
2. Use admin account from Tenant 1 to do admin-consent to the app registered in Azure AD of Tenant 2. Just need to open a browser and make a request to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client id of the app registered in Azure AD of Tenant 2}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={reply url of the app registered in Azure AD of Tenant 2}&nonce=1234&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&prompt=admin_consent
```

3. Log in with the admin account of Tenant 1 and click "Accept".[image: Accept screenshot]
4. Get the access token and use it to access Tenant 1 'abc.sharepoint.com'.

Comment: Thanks @allen-wu

I had already done the steps you indicated. The problem is not authentication. The problem is access to information on Tenant 1 'abc.sharepoint.com' when I am authenticated with the tenant user 2 'xyz.sharepoint.com'

Comment: After completing my steps, I can use a user from Tenant 2 to access to information on Tenant 1. For "authentication", my understanding is to get the access token.  What is the problem you are facing now?